# Artillery Io Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null

Tags: callback

While trying to run RampTo function in Artillery  I am getting the below error .

```
 config:

  target: 'https://reqres.in'

  phases:

    - duration: 120

      arrivalRate: 10

       rampTo: 20


   scenarios:

  - flow:

    - post:

        url: "/api/users"

        json:

          id1: "Harley"

          job: "Software Engineer"
```

if (!script.config.target && !options.environment) {

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null
>       at checkConfig (/home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/artillery/lib/util.js:151:21)
>       at fn (/home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
>       at /home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
>       at /home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
>       at /home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
>       at /home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
>       at Immediate. (/home/scrapbook/tutorial/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)

Comment: `script.config` is null, how are you loading it?

Comment: I am able to run the same code  just by removing rampTo: 20

Answer (score 1):

I know it been a long time but I got this error today and just fixed it.

In my case it was just `indentation` but in your case, you must change `target` value single-quote `'` to double-quote `"` like below:

```
config:
    target: "https://reqres.in"

phases:
    duration: 120
    arrivalRate: 10
    rampTo: 20

scenarios:
    flow:
        - post:
            url: "/api/users"
    json:
        id1: "Harley"
        job: "Software Engineer"
```

I fixed the indentation too, indentation is always a problem in `yaml` files.

Comment: I'm encountering this is as well and fixing whitespace / using double quotes / ensuring scenarios is top-level did not fix my problem. Also you'll need to indent all the json fields to be inside the post if that's to work